# PostgreSQL - Select only newer value

Tags: postgresql

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE public.element (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    elementname varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    element_sequence int4 NOT NULL,
    element_type varchar NOT NULL,
    creationdate timestamptz NOT NULL,
    validitystart date NOT NULL,
    validityend date NOT NULL,
);
```

What i need is to group by element_name and element_sequence and extract only the newer of every element.

So for example in a table like this

```
id|element_name|element_sequence|element_type|creationdate       |validityend|validitystar
--|------------|----------------|------------|-------------------|-----------|-------------|
 1|ab>cd       |               1|simple      |2020-06-18 09:09:00| 2020-06-20|   2020-06-18|
 2|ab>cd       |               1|simple      |2020-06-19 10:02:13| 2020-06-20|   2020-06-18|
 3|ab>cd       |               2|composite   |2020-06-19 10:02:15| 2020-06-20|   2020-06-18|
```

only id 2 and 3 should be extracted because 1 and 2 have the same element_name and the same element_sequence but id 2 is newer

Real table have more column, but for this example i used only the main

Answer (score 2):

maybe:

```
with latest as (
select element_name, element_sequence, max(creationdate) max_date from table group by element_name, element_sequence
)

select * --your column list
from table t
join latest lt on (lt.element_name = t.element_name and lt.element_sequence = t.element_sequence and lt.max_date = t.creationdate)
```

or

```
 select * from 
 (
 select element_name, element_sequence
, row_number() over (partition by element_name, element_sequence order by creationdate desc) lp -- you can add other columns
  from table 
  ) d
    where lp = 1
```

Comment: The last code is preferred (replacing the asterisk with separate column names list). First code must be used only when window functions are not available due to too ancient server version.